# Help in analysing dilatometer results

Tags: thermodynamics

I need some help in analysing results for a dilotometer experiment. I did this experiment for the first time and don't have any prior experience in this field. The main aim of this experiment was calculating the CTE( coefficent of thermal expansion). The type of dilatometer was a push rod dilatometer.

The sample was basic gamma alumina pellet of 19 mm by 3 mm. The pellet was a green body i.e it wasn't sintered. I have attached the resultant graph.

My main doubt is as follows -

1. The operating temperature was at 900 deg cel. For calculating the CTE or linear CTE in this case, do I consider only the intial length at 25 deg cel and final length at 900 deg cel, or do I take into account the up and down trends occuring in between.
2. I am fairly certain that at 900 deg cel the gamma alumina gets converted into another phase, how do I account for the phase changes?
   [image: Dilatometer result]

If anyone could guide me in how to analyse the graph, it would help me a lot. Sorry if this sounds like a basic question, I know homework questions aren't entertained here. This experiment is part of my QA/QC establishing process of my catalyst samples.

Comment: Since you used green material, it could have shrunk on sintering. Given this I suspect you can't get reliable expansion data at all.

Comment: But even if it's shrinks, I'll get a negative coefficent of thermal expansion right? I have seen people in literature reporting negative CTE values

Comment: Why even if? Why not because of ?After 110 min, it starts to turn toward negative, possibly due sintering ( and/or phase change), crossing zero near 155 min. // IMHO, dilation measurement makes sense either for bulk material, either for sintered one within T range of no observer sintering/phase changing.

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you for replying. After around 130 mins i.e when it reached 900 deg cel,  cooling was started.  Yes, I have planned do a similar experiment for a sintered body.

Comment: Hmm, then I have misinterpreted the chart, thinking 900 °C was reached at the end at about 175 min.